# Update page content cURL and ajax without page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

I've a form to send a ajax request which return a json object from a cURL request. I use the form to query the API using the start and and the end date. I've managed to show the datas returned into a table.
Now my problem is every time a make a new request from my form a new table is shown to the form page just after the table I've obtained with the previous request, is there any way to show only one table, so at every form request the previus data is replaced with the new data?

**This is my javascript code**

```
**$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to create table layout
  function createTable(data) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var header = table.insertRow();
    for(var h in data[0]) {
      var th = document.createElement('th');
      th.innerHTML = h;
      header.appendChild(th);
    }
    table.classList.add('table','table-bordered');
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      var row = table.insertRow();
      for(var v in item) {
        var cell = row.insertCell();
        if (Array.isArray(item[v])) {
          var subtable = createTable(item[v]);
          cell.appendChild(subtable);
        }
        else {
          cell.innerHTML = item[v];
        }
      }
    })
    return table;
  }
  // Initialize air datepicker plugin
  $('.air-datepicker').datepicker();
  // Store form into variable
  var form= $("#requestForm");
  // Actions when form is submitted
  $('#submitForm').click(function(e) {
    // Ajax request
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),

      success: function(result){
        // Show the table container
        $('#tableContainer').css('display','block');
        // Convert reponse into JSON
        datas = JSON.parse(result);
        // Get nome condominio and show it
        $('#nome_condominio').html(datas.condomini[0].condominio.nome);
        // Get indirizzo condomino and show it
        $('#indirizzo_condominio').html(datas.condomini[0].condominio.indirizzo);
        // Put datas into table using the function createTable
        var table = createTable(datas.condomini[0].ricevute);
        // Show table 
        $('#table').append(table);
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(error, status, xhr) {
        console.log(error, status, xhr);

      }
    }); // Fine ajax

   e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form to be sent
  }); // fine submit form

}); // fine document ready**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
// Show table
$('#table').html(table);
```

You replace the html content of the DOM node `#table` instead of appending the new table to existing content (including previuos generated tables).

Now, if `#table` is supposed to be empty at the time of the call then that solution is fine.

Otherwise if any content is present (ex. a table header) it's erased and you'll have to find a way to rebuild it.